# Serializing an object frequently whenever there is a value change in properties

Tags: c#, json, xml, serialization

I want to serialize an object whenever there is a change in the property value. Currently, INotifyPropertyChanged is not implemented in the class. What is the best practice to serialize the object frequently? Serialization should not hamper the application's performance. Please suggest NuGet packages if they can handle serializing the object frequently

Comment: It's impossible to answer such a broad and vague question. NuGet packages can't do anything that can't be done in C# code. You can either add a mechanism that publishes changes or you can compare before/after property values, which is the most expensive way possible. You can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Or instead of serializing in response to a property change, serialize as part of the command/operation that caused the change. Commands are very popular in both MVC and MVVM architectures. Actions in MVC architectures serve a similar purpose

Comment: I can initiate serialization as a part of command/operation change

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Check Newtonsoft.Json

var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);